# count[i] holds frequency for each character from a string how can i print only max count[i] from it in java

Tags: java

I am trying to print max repeated character from a string as output instead i am printing frequency of each character from string, please help me to print only maximum count and also if count[i] max value matches other characters i need to print that too. for example
aabbc 
for this i am getting output as a = 2 b = 2 c = 1
but output would be a = 2 b = 2

```
 int   counter[] = new int[256];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the string  :");
    String str = scan.next();
    for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++){
        // Count frequency of every character and store
        // it in counter array
        counter[(int) str.charAt(i)]++;
        //System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        //System.out.println(counter[i]);
        if (counter[i] != 0) {
            System.out.print(" "+(char) i + " = " + counter[i]);

             /*int ch = counter[i];
             System.out.println(ch);*/
            /*for(int b : counter[i]){

            }*/

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: find the max frequency and only print chahracters with that number

Comment: let me check rahul  instead of using  != you are asking me to keep counter[i]>1..?

Comment: Rahul i am getting below same out put 

Enter the string  :
aabba
 a = 3 b = 2

Answer (score 0):

the first loop is mapping your String, so for each character, you have value and key, and before you add it to your map check if it is already saved. and then loop through the map. something like this

```
// int   counter[] = new int[256];
//create new map
Map<String, int> charts = new HashMap<String, int>();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the string  :");
String str = scan.next();
for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++){
   if(charts.containsKey(str.charAt(i))){
      // add +1 to the map key
     charts.put(str.charAt(i),((int)charts.get(str.charAt(i)))+ 1);
    }else {
        // first time you add this you have count = 1
       charts.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
    }

}
 // loop through your map to get the data 
 for (Map.Entry<String, int> chart : charts.entrySet())
 {
    // you can check which one has the biggest value or whatever
     System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
 }
```

Code Not tested ^_^ but you get the idea

Comment: Thanks Hakim for your time ...map today only introduction taken let me try to work it out and reply back.

Comment: Are you allowed to use StringUtils.countMatches ?

Comment: i am trying to figure it out without using collections hakim as today only list and set topics covered